# why onBackPressed() always go back previous activity when i press physical back button?

Tags: android

After processed some activity, i want to exit the application.I implemented

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
       System.exit (0);
}
```

But my application is back to previous activity..I need exit my application completely.How to do that? 
I had searching a lot of article but it not working on that. 
My android is 2.3

Comment: what happens if you call `finish()` instead?

Comment: it also will go back previous activity

Comment: See [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Comment: if you start your activity with `startActivityForResult` your first activity can detect when the second has finished and optionally the first activity can then finish itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dldnh is right. You can monitor for finish, or you can finish first activity after you start second activity.

```
{
     Intent i = new Intent(this, com.second.class)
     startActivity(i);
     this.finish();
}
```

then in secound activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
       this.finish();
}
```